# How to generate DocuSign embedded signing url from apex?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I want to generate the DocuSign embedded URL to get the documents signed by the community user.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to achieve the requirement. Here is the solution

Initial things

1. DocuSign setup from both sides (Salesforce and DocuSign itself).
2. Signing user must be assigned “DocuSign Sender” permission set to sign the
   document(s).

**Create and send an envelope** – First method

```
public static String sendEnvelope(String recordId) {
  Id mySourceId = recordId; // The ID of the initiating Salesforce object
  // Create an empty envelope and add a Salesforce Document and embedded signer  
     recipient
  // The embedded signer will be the current user with sequence and routing 
     order 1 and role "Signer 1" by default
  List<dfsle.Document> myDocuments = new List<dfsle.Document>();
      // Content Version need to be param or queried 
        myDocuments = 
             dfsle.DocumentService.getDocuments(ContentVersion.getSObjectType(),
             new Set<Id> { ContentVersionId(s) });  
 dfsle.Envelope dsEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
 new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId))//The initiating Salesforce entity current SF user 
    .withDocuments(myDocuments)
    .withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> {
    dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner() // An embedded signer
 }
);

// Send the envelope.
dsEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
    dsEnvelope, // The envelope to send
    true // Send now?
);
// Return string value of DocuSign envelope ID
return String.valueOf(dsEnvelope.docuSignId);
```

}

**Host an embedded signing session** – second method

```
// passing envId as parameter that we will receive from above method
public static String getEmbeddedSigningUrl(String envId) {
    //  url will be redirect URL
    Url mySigningUrl = dfsle.SigningService.getEmbeddedSigningUrl(
                     dfsle.UUID.parse(envId), // envId value as a UUID
                     new URL(url) // url value as a URL
                   );
    // Return string value of url to controller
    return mySigningUrl.toExternalForm();
```

}

1. **Variable Source id** – It is the parent object record id where we want to store the signed documents back into salesforce.
2. Set of content version ids which are stored as files with s1,d1 tags etc.

   ```
   myDocuments = 
            dfsle.DocumentService.getDocuments(ContentVersion.getSObjectType(),    
            new Set<Id> { ContentVersionId(s) });
   ```
3. Redirect URL - After signing the document(s) where we want to redirect the user.
4. In the case of using DocuSign in the context of Community user
   Note: In the DocuSign Setup tab choose Configuration in the left menu, then go to the Settings tab and choose a user next to Enable System sender. This allows Community users to send envelopes even if they are not a member of the DocuSign account. In that case, envelopes will be sent from the admin user that you selected.

**Important Points to remember**
Embedded URL is valid only for 5 mins by default, if we want to increase the time
we will have to talk to the DocuSign support team and it can be increased max up
to 15 mins depending on the service plan.

**References**
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/embedded-sending-signing/